# Adding and debugging external project

Tags: android, gradle, module

I am developing an android app. I have added a new project to my gradle build as follows....
In the build.gradle I have added...

```
android {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':code-scanner')
    }
...
}
```

In the settings.gradle I have added...

```
include ":code-scanner"
project(':code-scanner').projectDir = new File(settingsDir , "../External/code-scanner")
```

The project builds fine. But I would like to be able to browse the source, and add breakpoints to the code-scanner project, but it does not show up in Android Studio.

I have tried importing module , but the folder is missing from the subsequent select folder dialog.

How can I add this code to android studio, and set breakpoints and debug....

Comment: Any chance your using Git for both `code-scanner` and your app? If they are in two separate Git repo's then you could use git submodules and include `code-scanner` in your app while keeping commit history of both separate. That way you code have a folder with `code-scanner` alone, and your app which has a copy of  `code-scanner` in it which you easily place breakpoints in.

Comment: The issue was a brainfart on my part. Basically there is not issue. No answer will be marked as correct, as there is not issue to confirm a correct solution.

Comment: I guess you figured that you can place breakpoints in someway inside `code-scanner` lib code even if the project does not have the source files, am I right? :P

Comment: No my project shows the project, I can browse the source files, and everything works. I simply opened from a branch that did not contain the code-scanner code.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. Based on [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-types) dependencies should be defined outside **android** block. Maybe Gradle Build figures out your code, but your Android Studio can't find source code of your library.
What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Actually if you try to do the same it'll work, I just did after thinking (theoretically) about it and it did work, it's because `android` block does not have a definition for `dependencies` so it'll be resolved and called at the project model, that's the nice thing about `build.gradle` being a groovy script

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure you put `implementation project(':code-scanner')` in app level `build.gradle` file

2- `dependencies` block should not be inside `android` block:

Not like this:

```
android {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':code-scanner')
    }
}
```

But like this:

```
android {
...
...
}

dependencies {
        implementation project(':code-scanner')
}
```

I don't know which IDE you are using but most IDEs like Android Studio or IntelliJ look like the pictures below.

[image: Android Studio Android View]

Or you can view your folder structure in Project view like this:

[image: Android Studio Project View]

If you didn't accidentally delete it, it should be there.

Comment: I only have one build.gradle, and no build.gradle in the app module.

Comment: `dependencies` block can be in `android` and Gradle won't complain, go ahead and try or read my comments on previous answers

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is the location of the project, which is outside of the root project directory:

```
include ":code-scanner"
// project(':code-scanner').projectDir = new File(settingsDir , "../External/code-scanner")
```

Better add it as a library module *within* the root project, then the code should be within IDE scope.

If you don't want to move the project into there, you could put a built artifact into the `libs` directory.

Adding a symbolic link might also work out (it's rather a file-system issue than a Gradle issue).

Comment: the thing about the dependencies block isn't entirely wrong, it's true it's not usual but it does work (check my comment on previous answer)

Comment: @ahasbini I've wrote "should" and not "must". And I've honestly never checked if it makes any real difference (this could as well be a common misconception). Nevertheless, moving that project or it's AAR artifact within the scope of the root project should make it's code debuggable.

Answer (score -1):

'code-scanner' project you have to add as a library to the current project,for that in code-scanner build.gradle file you have to add 
**apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**
please check if it is missing.